# Как сделать подчёркивание за текстом

Tags: css

Как реализовать подчеркивание, как на картинке?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

Один из вариантов, такой:

```css
h2>span {
  position: relative;
}

h2>span:before {
  height: 4px;
  background-color: orange;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 4px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h2><span>Наши</span> <span>партнёры</span> <span>по</span> <span>бизнесу</span></h2>
<h2><span>Наши партнёры по бизнесу</span></h2>
```